# Getting "unauthorized_client" error while regenerating new Microsoft token in OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

We are using [OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) for admin authentication. We are using this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) to regenerate the admin oauth token. But we are getting the below error for a user when generating the token after token becomes invalid. Can you please advise on this?

`{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000112: Application 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'(<app-name>) is disabled.\r\nTrace ID: ec4b3557-143a-4020-9651-5cdaf0f83900\r\nCorrelation ID: 97a\r\nTimestamp: 2022-04-28 00:3sdew34fdddddddddd7:47Z","error_codes":[7000112],"timestamp":"2022-04-28 00:37:47Z","trace_id":"ec4b3557-143a-4020-9651-5cdaf0f83900","correlation_id":"9e5ewferferfge753476fergerf97a"}`

Answer (score 0):

It means your Graph application is either not installed or is disabled for that particular Exchange tenant. Make sure it is property registered - start at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2